# Chaining safe navigation operator in Angular not working as expected

Tags: angular

I am using the safe navigator feature in Angular 6+

I am subscribing to an observable with property values that come in at different times.

```
user.username
user.attributes.given_name
user.attributes.family_name
```

If I use `{{ user?.username }}` everything works as expected.

However when I use `{{ user?.attributes?.given_name }}` or `{{ user?.attributes?.family_name}}` I don't get an error, but my values never display in the view.

I can't use `{{ user.attributes?.given_name }}` or `{{ user?.attributes.given_name }}` as each causes an error for getting properties of undefined.

As I understand it it's just fine to chain the safe navigation operator like this. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. It means that there is no data to navigate to as you yourself have mentioned.

Comment: The data does eventually come in. I can get it in the console. But it never resolves in the view. I was under the impression that it would as it does when I use only one save navigation operator. Is it different when you chain them?

Comment: No because safe-navigation is translated into something like `user && user.attributes && user.attributes.family_name` which is valid javascript. This sounds like a problem with change detection not triggering on the data.  If you are on onPush CD you have to mutate the reference on user, not user.attributes. You can test whether it's a CD issue by subscribing to the observable and doing `changeDetectorRef.markForChanges()`, you have to inject the CDRef in the constructor.